# How to make plots with small whitespace separations in Matplotlib or Seaborn?

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, ggplot2, seaborn

I'd like to make this type of plot with multiple columns separated by small whitespace, each having different category having 3-5 (5 in this example) different observations with varying values on y axis:

[image: Plot]

Comment: That looks rather straight-forward for `ggplot2`. Do you have sample data? Have you tried anything? This appears to be a request for a free code-writing service, typically not very welcome on SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

actually, i can plot this plot use ggplot2. for example:

```html
head(mtcars)
# mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
# Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1

library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
mtcars %>% reshape2::melt() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = variable, y = value)) + 
  geom_point() + facet_grid(~ variable) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())
```

you set a categorical variable in your dataset,then use the `facet_grid(~)`.this function can change your plot into multiple plot by your categrical variable

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach to draw a similar plot using Python's matplotlib. The plot has a grey background and white major and minor gridlines to delimit the zones. Getting the dots in the center of each little cell is somewhat tricky: divide into n+1 spaces and shift half a cell (1/2n). A secondary x-axis can be used to set the labels. A `zorder` has to be set to have the dots on top of the gridlines.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import ticker

n = 5
cols = 7
values = [np.random.uniform(1, 10, n) for c in range(cols)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_facecolor('lightgrey')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1 / (n)))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1))
ax.grid(True, which='both', axis='both', color='white')
ax.set_xticklabels([])
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='both', length=0)
ax.grid(which='major', axis='both', lw=3)
ax.set_xlim(1, cols + 1)
for i in range(1, cols + 1):
    ax.scatter(np.linspace(i, i + 1, n, endpoint=False) + 1 / (2 * n), values[i-1], c='crimson', zorder=2)

ax2 = ax.twiny()
ax2.set_xlim(0.5, cols + 0.5)
ticks = range(1, cols + 1)
ax2.set_xticks(ticks)
ax2.set_xticklabels([f'Cat_{t:02d}' for t in ticks])
bbox = dict(boxstyle="round", ec="limegreen", fc="limegreen", alpha=0.5)
plt.setp(ax2.get_xticklabels(), bbox=bbox)
ax2.tick_params(axis='x', length=0)

plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]